# IOS dispatch_get_main_queue() is called multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, reachability

I test internet connection with `Reachability` and  `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` 
when I test the following code it works but it is called multiple times.

Parent:

```
@protocol RootViewDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
-(void)internetIsDownGoToRoot;
@end
- (void)testInternetConnection
{
    internetReachableFoo = [ReachabilityTony reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    // Internet is reachable
    internetReachableFoo.reachableBlock = ^(ReachabilityTony *reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Yayyy, we have the interwebs!");
            [weakSelf sendLoginRequest];
        });
    };
        // Internet is not reachable
internetReachableFoo.unreachableBlock = ^(ReachabilityTony *reach)
{
    // Update the UI on the main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Someone broke the internet :(");
        CloudConnection *sharedInstance=[CloudConnection  sharedInstance];
        sharedInstance.isUserLoggedIN=NO;
        //update login button
        [weakSelf updateButtons];
        [weakSelf notifyChild];

    });
};
    [internetReachableFoo startNotifier];
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[self testInternetConnection];
 }
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    internetReachableFoo= nil;

}
//notify childs no connection come back to root
-(void) notifyChild
{
    [delegate internetIsDownGoToRoot];

}
```

Child:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    NSArray *viewControllers =     self.navigationController.viewControllers;
    int count = [viewControllers count];
    id previousController = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:count - 2];
    RootViewController *rvc= previousController;
    rvc.delegate=self;


}

-(void)internetIsDownGoToRoot
{
    //internet connection is no avaliable go to root
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

So this is parentview lets say I push-pop childview 5 times and shutdown internet. I see on nslog that

```
Someone broke the internet :(
Someone broke the internet :(
Someone broke the internet :(
Someone broke the internet :(
Someone broke the internet :(
```

as you can see I have added `internetReachableFoo= nil;` but I doesnt change anything.

Whats going on with above code, why it is called multiple times?

What is the possible dangers of using this block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called multiple times because every time you pop the child, the root gets `-viewDidAppear:` and calls `-testInternetConnection`, which re-runs the reachability test.

**Update:** Ok you've changed your question slightly. The reason why you're getting 5 "did disappear" messages is because you never stop the notifier. Reachability keeps itself alive as long as it's running, so nilling out your reference isn't killing it. You need to explicitly say `[internetReachableFoo stopNotifier]` before nilling it out.

Comment: I know thats why I call it in `didappear` , but why it is called 5 or 3 times at once, it is supposed to call once every `viewdidappear`

Comment: If you're doubting this to be the case, you can confirm (or disprove) that it's being called by this method by putting a `breakpoint` on the first line of your `testInternetConnection` method and then checking the `Debug Navigator` tab (third from the right in the navigation pane on the left) to see the method call stack chain.

Comment: @MordFustang: Ok I've updated my answer to cover your edited question.